# Identifying what Rowkeys are stored on which node in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I would like to know if there is any script/tool available to identify which Cassandra node has a particular rowkey and which node has its replica data in a situation where replication_factor=2, numtokens=256 and partitioner=Murmer3

It could be done with some computation manually but would like to know if there is any readily available tool? This is primarily to characterize the system and benchmark response times when certain replicas go down.

Answer (score 3):

nodetool getendpoints keyspace cf key

where the key is in HEX format will tell you the end points which own the key.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but does it identify just the primary replica or does it tell the nodes that have secondary replica as well?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use the Cassandra JMX interface  http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/JmxInterface#org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.Operations.getNaturalEndpoints